# can I install postgres 9.0 from repos on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I currently have 8.3 postgres on ubuntu I installed using apt-get. can I install 9.0 beside it from repos instead of compiling from source? I really dont want to deal with dependencies since I am running ubuntu 9.04 and I think I am missing libreadline6 and its stuff.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to upgrade to 10.04 (lucid).

You can do it with

```
do-release-upgrade
```

Add this to your /etc/apt/sources.list and run `aptitude update`

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitti/postgresql/ubuntu lucid main
```

Source: https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/postgresql and http://www.piware.de/2010/09/postgresql-9-0-final-released/

Comment: thanks for the reply. Upgrading ubuntu is an option but I wanted to take a shortcut. I guess I might aswell look into it.